# Не работает простой js-код

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые спецы по `js`, помогите! имеем массив коэффициентов `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` для слагаемых суммы: `F=a1+a2+a3+a4+a5`. Нужно чтобы программа пробегала массив и там, где коэффициент равен `1` возвращала слагаемое `a` c номером коэффициента, т.е. в нашем случае это `a1` и `a3`. А там где коэффициент равен `0` возвращался бы ноль. А в конце например `alert'om` выводилась бы сумма, в нашем случае `F=a1+a3`. Не знаю как это сделать. у меня есть вариант записи возвращаемых слагаемых в массив, т.е. `[a1, 0, a3, 0, 0]`, а затем суммирование его элементов, но это не работает, вот код:

```
var mass_a = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
var F = 0
var mid = [];
function summa() {
    for (var i=0; i<mass_a.length; i++) {
        if (mass_a[i] == 1) {
        arg = a[i]}; 
        else if (mass_a[i] == 0) {
        arg = 0};
        mid.push([arg]); 
        F+=mid[i];
        alert(F);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает простой JS-код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264798/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-js-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4)

Answer (score 4):

Может как то так?

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var mask = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1];
var summ = 0;

for (var i=0; i < mask.length; i++) {
    if (mask[i] == 1) summ = summ + values[i];
}

alert(summ);
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/DvM7t/

Comment: А зачече if в данном случае? если коэффициенты только нули и единицы, то просто summ += values[i]*a[i]