# Не работает простой JS-код

Tags: javascript, java, массивы

Есть массив коэффициентов `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` для слагаемых суммы:  `F=a1+a2+a3+a4+a5`.

Нужно чтобы программа пробегала массив и там, где коэффициент равен 1 возвращала слагаемое `a` c номером коэффициента, т.е. в нашем случае это `a1` и `a3`.

Там где коэффициент равен 0 возвращался бы ноль, а в конце например, `alert` выводилась бы сумма, в нашем случае `F=a1+a3`.

Не знаю как это сделать. У меня есть вариант записи возвращаемых слагаемых в массив, т.е. `[a1, 0, a3, 0, 0]`, а затем суммирование его элементов, но это не работает.
Вот код:

```
var mass_a = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
var F = 0
var mid = [];
function summa() {
    for (var i=0; i<mass_a.length; i++) {
        if (mass_a[i] == 1) {
        arg = a[i]}; 
        else if (mass_a[i] == 0) {
        arg = 0};
        mid.push([arg]); 
        F+=mid[i];
        alert(F);
  } 
}
```

Comment: отформатируйте хоть своё творчество что ли, товарищ прапорщик

Answer (score 2):

я так понял можно упростить до безобразия:

```
function summa(mass_a) 
{ 
 var F = "";
 for (var i=0; i<mass_a.length; i++) 
 { 
    if (mass_a[i] == 1) 
        { F += "a" + (i + 1) + " "};
 }
 return F;
}

summa([1,0,1,0,0])
```